# Dudas en el uso de la función filter

Tags: javascript

A la siguiente función se le pasa un array que contiene elementos true y false. Devuelve la cantidad de trues que hay en el array.
La segunda forma de la función la entiendo perfectamente pero no la primera.
En la primera forma de la función no entiendo ¿cómo pasándole la palabra Boolean crea un nuevo array solo de elementos trues? ¿Boolean es una palabra reservada o es un parámetro?

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) {
    return arrayOfSheeps.filter(Boolean).length;
}

function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) {
    return arrayOfSheeps.filter(elem =>elem == true).length;
}
```

Comment: Aunque @Triby ya ha dado una respuesta válida, comentar para completar la respuesta a otros usuarios que también puedes llegar a verlo de la siguiente manera (bajo la misma condición de filtrado): `return arrayOfSheeps.filter(elem => elem).length`, debido a la comprobación de valores truly/falsy

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Boolean es una palabra reservada o es un parámetro?

Ni lo uno ni lo otro, [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Boolean) es un objeto y se puede instanciar con o sin la palabra reservada **new**. Lo que pasa aquí es que el método [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) ejecuta la función de retorno (callback) para cada elemento del arreglo y, si recibe verdadero, agrega el elemento al arreglo resultante.

```
Boolean(true) // Devuelve verdadero y se agrega el elemento
Boolean(false) // Devuelve falso y omite el elemento
```

Para ilustrar un poco mejor, en este ejemplo `comprobacion()` "hace lo mismo" que `Boolean()`, solo agrega salida a la consola.

```js
// No se especifican argumentos
function comprobacion() {
    // Sin embargo, .filter() sí envía argumentos
    console.log(...arguments);
    // Se devuelve el valor recibido en primer argumento verdadero || falso
    return arguments[0];
}

let arr = [true, false, true, false];
console.log(arr.filter(comprobacion).length);
```

Con *"hace lo mismo"* me refiero solo a este ejemplo, donde simplemente toma un valor (falso o verdadero) y lo devuelve. Realmente `Boolean()` trabaja de forma diferente.